# Share Desktop VPN with WMDC-connected WinMo 6.1 Device

Tags: networking, vpn, windows-mobile, windows-mobile-device-center

We have a website that we use to feed web services to a .NET Compact app on some old WinMo 6.1 devices. *(Believe me, I'm WELL aware they are dinosaur-dead per MS, unfortunately, it's what the client uses.)*

What with the current WFH/Covid situation I'm trying to hit our site with the development handheld here at home. In order to hit the site though, I need to be connected to our office VPN (it is not available public). It all works great on my laptop. I connect the VPN, I hit the site, it comes up. Golden.

It seems though that the WMDC connection does not share out access to the VPN resources to the handheld. If I try to pull up the site on the handheld, it times out, and says that the server could not be found. I can pull up other, public sites on the handheld while cradled, without issue.

Anyone have any idea how to get the VPN and its protected resources to be visible/available to the handheld in the cradle? The cradle is plugged in to my laptop via USB.

Handheld is a Motorola MC3090 running WinMo 6.1.
My laptop is running Windows 10, build 19042.685.
VPN is Sonicwall Global VPN Client v.4.10.2.0428
WMDC is v.6.1.6965

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, ... turns out after digging in more, this was NOT because of the VPN vs. the cradle. The issue was actually that these dinosaur terminals apparently have trouble with DNS name resolution. When I replace the domain name with the IP address of the site, everything works fine. Wonderful. ‍♂️ And that, is good enough. Don't care as long as it's working.